# laravel showing modified values in form

Tags: forms, laravel

Maybe this is a simple question but I couldn't find a solution.

I am building a form to modify a document which has the following fields:
`lesson_title`, `day_id`, `speaker_id` and `file`.

Saving the documents works quite well, the problem rises when I want to edit the single record. This is what I am using:

```
{{ Form::model($document, array('route' => array('admin.material.update', $document->id),'files' => true, 'method' => 'put')) }}
<p>
    {{ Form::label('Lesson title') }}
    {{ Form::text('lesson_title') }}
</p>
<p>
    {{ Form::label('Speaker') }}
    {{ Form::select('speaker_id', Speaker::lists('fullname', 'id')) }}
</p>
<p>
    {{ Form::label('Day of the lesson') }}
    {{ Form::text('masterday_id', array('class' => 'form-control','id' => 'calendar')) }}
</p>
<p>
    {{ Form::label('Material','Select the material to insert') }}
    {{ Form::label('file') }}
    {{ Form::file('file') }}
</p>
    {{ Form::button('Save', ['type' => 'submit']) }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

For the speaker I don't have any problem since the `Speaker::lists` gives the list of name connected to their relative id.

I have a problem with the `masterday_id`, which is the id in the table `masterdays`. A record in this table has just one field that is `day` (and is formatted as a date).

I would like that, in my `Form::text('masterday_id')` it would be possible to see the `day` related to that id, not the id.

Similar problem for the `Form::label('file')` where I see all the extension, the complete path, while I would like to see just the name of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the `masterday_id` you'll need to create a relation in your model (if you haven't already)

```
public function masterday(){
    return $this->hasOne('Masterday');
}
```

Then you can use this syntax to retrieve a field from that related model:

```
Form::text('masterday[day]');
```

---

For `file`, you can use an [attribute accessor](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators):

```
public function getFilenameAttribute(){
    return basename($this->attributes['file']);
}
```

Usage:

```
{{ Form::label('filename') }}
```